# How many consumers are created to read records per direct stream?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I'm using Spark Streaming to read data from Kafka (using the [Kafka direct stream API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html)).

How many Kafka consumers are instantiated for a stream? Is the number of Kafka consumers equal to the number of executors? Does each executor instantiate one Kafka consumer (with the same group id)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With direct approach number of consumers [will be exactly the same as the number of Kafka Partitions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html):

> The Spark Streaming integration for Kafka 0.10 is similar in design to the 0.8 Direct Stream approach. It provides simple parallelism, 1:1 correspondence between Kafka partitions and Spark partitions, and access to offsets and metadata

and the separate consumer [is initialized for each partition](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/39e2bad6a866d27c3ca594d15e574a1da3ee84cc/external/kafka-0-8/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/kafka/KafkaRDD.scala#L159).

Comment: It says that the number of 'partitions' would be 1:1, not number of 'consumers'.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. A follow-up question: Are these consumers created on the executors? I'm guessing yes, but just wanted to confirm nonetheless.